# Why slow query in mysql when the search result is zero?

Tags: mysql, database

I don't understand why if I have a query that takes 0,0015 sec to retrieve results from a table of 8.000.000 records, the same query takes about 10 sec when the search result is zero.
I have a composite index like index (A,B,C) and my query is something like:

```
select * from table where A = 'string' AND 
    (B LIKE '%sstring1%' OR strcmp(soundex(B),soundex('string1')) = 0) AND (C LIKE '%string2%' 
      OR strcmp(soundex(B),soundex('string1')) = 0)
```

If the result find something it takes about 0.0015, but in case of zero results it takes 10 sec that is to long for my purpose. What's the reason of this behavior? How can I resolve it?

Thank you in advance for your answer or advice.

Comment: Try `EXPLAIN` to see how the indexes are actually used.

Comment: i've used explain and what it says is quite similar for both case, when i find something or not. The index is used and also the numbers of rows involved are similar.What can i do to find out more?

Comment: I'd start by simplifying the query. One thing that makes finding nothing slow is that you have to try all terms. So try each of the 4 terms separately to find out which is slow (and whether it is so in both cases or just the non-match case).

Comment: searching on the mysql documentation i've find a lot of problem in my query: first of all with strcmp or soundex i can't use indexes and with LIKE form that starts with % the indexes are not used. Morover with an (A,B,C) index only if A is wrong i can have a result in 0.008 sec, otherwise the research has to go through the all terms. I'm planning to change the query and make it from the beginning.

Comment: One thing you could do, is store the soundex values in the table as extra columns, that way they can be indexed and you can search them faster.

Comment: thanks @towr! i'll do it